# Where do Call Logs get stored in Salesforce?

Tags: case, tasks

Call Log records are created and associated to Cases by our CTI app, when I click on the Call Log, it takes me to the task record which I can re-associate with the "RelatedTo" field.

However when re-associating, the original Case under its Case Feed still displays the Call Log not the new case. I'd like to know what object does this sit in so I can reparent using some sort of trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publisher actions such as Log a Call create at least two objects: one is the Activity (a Task or Event) and the other is a Chatter post. The feed post is parented on the record's feed upon which the Activity is logged and persists information about the Task or Event at the time it was created.

The feed post is not being updated when you reparent the Task itself, and maintains the original presence in the Case feed. You'll probably have to locate and delete the relevant `FeedItem` to get rid of this record.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Log a Call' action creates the Task object under the Case.

Here you can find some differeces between Logging a Call and creating a New Task:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giJlAAI